# Align header element alongside image

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a small menu panel that needs to be included on my page that looks like the image below:

[image: Menu Panel]

I have the code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/wRkdL/24/)  that I have created so far and I know some of the images are incorrect but the issue is I cannot get the header to align neatly to the right of the image as shown in the image.

```
Any clues?
```

Comment: it might help to know which browser you are getting this issue on

Comment: No. It must be a CSS change only.

Comment: @atar All browsers. If it was only specific browsers I would have specified them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed 2 properties:

```
ul.block-with-icons span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 98px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wRkdL/25/

Comment: Thanks for the solution above. It works and is great and is the solution I was looking for using only CSS therefore I have awarded the answer credit to you as @Aljullu 's solution required the modification of html code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in HTML5, I think the best option is to move `<h5>` inside `<a>` tag like this:

```
<li class="b1">
<a href="#">
<h5>Our background</h5>
<span>A little background info on who we are...</span>
</a>
</li>
```

In HTML4 it's not allowed to insert a block element inside anchors.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's going to be a mixture :-( . Our system is programmed in PL/SQL and outputs XHTML (I believe) and our client has provided most of their code and CSS in the form of a template that we incorporate into our system that is written in HTML5.